# Common configuration 2 - commented properties

Tags: java

i'm developing a java desktop application to use as a tool to manipulate properties files.
So my application need to  to load a TXT file containing several keys (or properties), and be able to changes there values.
I use [Apache commons configurations 2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration) project to do this work.
Everything was going well until a face this situation..
there is a txt file contating several properties but, one properties (or key) has a # before his name (look at config.txt file below), so apache commons do not recognize this propertie.
When i set a value to this propertie (look at last two lines on main method), apache commons configurator creates a new line on config.txt

This is not good to me, because i need to preserve the original config.txt format, so if i need to set a value to fileDb propertie, my expected behavior is to remove the # from fileDb name and do not create a new fileDb propertie on config.txt.

the program that uses this configuration file (config.txt) understands that if the property is commented (if it has "#" in its name), it means that it should not be used, but if it is uncommented (without "#" in the name) means that it should be used and that its value should be read.

So what can i do to add or remove "#" from the propertie name using common configuration? if is not possible to do it with commons configurator, how to do it?

On the ConfigTest class i show how the problem ocours.
Before run the code, the file config.txt has a commented propertie named fileDB

```
    #fileDb = C:/test/test.db
```

the maind method try to change the filedb value to "C://aa//bb//cc"
but after the executions end wil appears a new propetie with the same name "fileDb" but uncomented (without "#"). At the end, config.txt wil have two fileDb propertie, one with "#" and other without "#"

```
    #fileDb = C:/test/test.db
    fileDb = C://aa//bb//cc
```

My expectd behavior after the code execution is to has only one fileDb propetie

```
    fileDb = C://aa//bb//cc
```

After be able to uncoment this propertie i expect to be able to comment again if necessery (if user wish to do it on my app).

#### ConfigTest class

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.FileBasedConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.FileBasedBuilderParameters;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException;

import java.io.File;
public class ConfigTest {

    private Configuration localConfiguration;
    private FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> fileBuilder;

private ConfigTest() throws ConfigurationException {
    this.loadPropertiesFile();
}

private void loadPropertiesFile() throws ConfigurationException {
    File file = new File("config.txt");
    FileBasedBuilderParameters fb = new Parameters().fileBased();
    fb.setFile(file);
    fileBuilder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class);
    fileBuilder.configure(fb);
    localConfiguration = fileBuilder.getConfiguration();
}

public boolean saveModifications(){
    try {
        fileBuilder.save();
        return true;
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void setProperty(String key, String value){
    localConfiguration.setProperty(key,value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {

    ConfigTest test = new ConfigTest();
    //change outputOnSSD propertie value to false
    test.setProperty("outputOnSSD", "false");
    //here when i set a new value to fileDb propertie, a new line on config.txt with a new fileDb propertie name is created
    //the question is: how to remove # from fileDb propetie name on config.txt to commons config recognize it as a existent propertie?
    test.setProperty("fileDb", "C://aa//bb//cc");
    test.saveModifications();

}

}
```

#### File "config.txt" used by ConfigTest class to change his value

```
########################################################################
# Local environment configuration
########################################################################

# Defines program localization/language
locale = pt-BR

# Temporary directory for processing: "default" uses the system temporary folder.
indexTemp = /home/downloads

# Enable if is on a SSD disk.
indexTempOnSSD = true

# Enable if output/case folder is on SSD. If enabled, index is created directly in case folder,
outputOnSSD = false

# Number of processing threads/workers: "default" uses the number of CPU logical cores.
numThreads = 14

# Full path for hash index database. 
#fileDb = C:/test/test.db
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.